# How to adapt the many' to return Left in attoparsec of Haskel

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

For example

```
parseTest :: Parser Int
parseTest = char '(' *> return 1 <* char ')'

parseTests :: Parser [Int]
parseTests = many' $ char '(' *> return 1 <* char ')'

parseOnly ParseIni.parseTest "(" -- returns Left with error
parseOnly ParseIni.parseTests "(" -- returns Right with []
```

How can I make the second one to return Left with lost `)`, and I also want to parse the case with empty string with answer `Right []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the doc on `parseOnly`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.2.2/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#v:parseOnly)

> To force a parser to consume all of its input, use something like this:
>
> ```
> parseOnly (myParser <* endOfInput)
> ```

---

`ParseIni.parseTests` applies the parser `char '(' *> return 1 <* char ')'` zero or more times. It always succeeds, as it can at least apply it zero times. Thus you need to ensure it consumed everything by composing it with `endOfInput`.

```
parseOnly (ParseIni.parseTests <* endOfInput) "("
```